# Setup a Typescript project with classes shared between client and server apps?

Tags: node.js, typescript, ntvs

I currently have a solution with two projects. ServerApp (nodejs NTVS) and BrowserApp (Html Typescript application).

I wish to share classes between both projects and get immediate intellisense.

How to do that ?

PS: for those how know GWT, what I want is similar to the shared project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to do it this way :

- create a third project named SharedClasses (I used HTML Typescript template)
- add my shared classes in it
- add a shared_reference.ts file with references to those classes files
- add a link to the reference.ts file in ServerApp and BrowserApp projects that point to shared_reference.ts

`/// <reference path="../SharedClasses/shared_reference.ts" />`

Autocompletion works, F12 too...

Answer (score 0):

If you use an external build tool e.g `grunt-ts` its easier. For a demo check out : https://github.com/basarat/demo-fullstack

With a sample gruntfile (https://github.com/basarat/demo-fullstack/blob/master/src/Gruntfile.js). Important bit:

```
  var commonFiles = "common/**/*.ts";
  var serverFiles = ["server/**/*.ts", commonFiles];
  var clientFiles = ["client/**/*.ts", commonFiles];
```